# SQL Error when running Subquery on db2 10.1

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, birt

We are trying to put a complex query into BIRT in order to get a report with a 'sum' as one of the values.  We are generating the sum using a recursive CTE.

The query we have is as follows:
`007 WITH CTETASKLIST(
008     SUPERVISORUSERNAME ,
009     SUBORDINATEUSERNAME
010 ) AS(
011     SELECT
012         SUPERVISORUSERNAME ,
013         SUBORDINATEUSERNAME
014     FROM
015         DBRO.SUBORDINATELINK
016     WHERE
017         SUBORDINATEUSERNAME = ?
018 UNION ALL SELECT
019         S.SUPERVISORUSERNAME ,
020         S.SUBORDINATEUSERNAME
021     FROM
022         DBRO.SUBORDINATELINK AS S ,
023         CTETASKLIST AS T
024     WHERE
025         S.SUPERVISORUSERNAME = T.SUBORDINATEUSERNAME
026 ) SELECT
027     OWNERFULLNAME ,
028     TOTALTASKS ,
029     (
030         SELECT
031             SUM(TA2.TOTALTASKS)
032         FROM
033             CTETASKLIST AS CTE JOIN DBRO.USERTASKTOTAL AS TA2
034                 ON TA2.OWNERUSERNAME = CTE.SUBORDINATEUSERNAME
035     ) AS SUMTA
036 FROM
037     DBRO.USERTASKTOTAL AS TA
038 WHERE
039     OWNERUSERNAME = ?`

Our software versions are:
BIRT: 2.6.1
DB2: 10.1

The test data we have is guaranteed to terminate (no infinite recursion).

The error we are getting is SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601.  The parser marks the '(' of the sub query (line 29) as an unexpected character.

Exact error message: [image]

This query runs completely fine when run against the database directly (using DBEaver, for example).  However, when we paste it into BIRT, it generates the error message.  Does anyone know why this is happening or have a way around the problem?  Unfortunately, we can't upgrade the version of BIRT because it is part of a different software product.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that OWNERFULLNAME in line 27 is parsed incorrectly. Try rewriting OWNERFULLNAME text (maybye there are invalid characters inside that text). Another idea which you can try is to reduce the number of lines in this query (at least for troubleshooting purposes).

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a computed column in your data set, to calculate your sum?

Comment: @kazik1616 we double checked the database and don't have any invalid characters.  The sample above is the "simple" version of the query; the actual query will be longer and have more fields.

Comment: @JamesJenkins We are trying to use this query as part of a computed column in BIRT.  That's when we see this error.  Just running the query against DB2 is working fine...  Or do you mean having a column in the DB itself?

Comment: I mean; In BIRT edit the Data set, select "Computed Columns" and create a computed column with JavaScript.  Using the BIRT feature gives you alot more options than trying to create the column with SQL.

Comment: @JamesJenkins we thought about that, but since we were using nested tables, we didn't think that would work.  we'll revisit that option and see if the JS can handle it.